US PhD after Europe Masters in Neuroscience timeline question
I am about to enter the second year of a masters program in cognitive neuroscience at a well known school in the EU. I am originally from the united states and am hoping to continue my academic career in america.
I am wondering though what the timeline would be. Most PhD programs I have seen include two years before the final project that consist of internships and coursework, much like a master, and often include the granting of an MS along the way.
Already having an MS in cognitive neuroscience, Would I be required to complete those preliminary years of coursework at US universities, or would I be able to skip to the final project, shortening the total time of the PhD? Thank you! I am specifically looking at Harvard, UCSD, and MIT. I have 5 papers (2 first author, 1 co-author, 2 second+ author) and a stellar academic record.

Since you have already a good CV, you should care about Harvard, UCSD, MIT only in hte future if you got a professorship position from them, not to rot there as a PhD under the pressure to keep up their prestige.


Would I be required to complete those preliminary years of coursework at US universities

Yes.

would I be able to skip to the final project, shortening the total time of the PhD?

No, you won't be able to skip.
A US PhD research project in cognitive neuroscience does not start when your courses are finished. If it's a 5 year PhD you're expected to spend 5 years doing research. You're expected to take some courses your first couple years at the same time, but that doesn't mean you're not doing research then. Depending on the program you may be given several months to rotate around and choose an advisor, but once that's done you get started immediately.
On a program-to-program basis it's possible (but unlikely) you'd be allowed to skip/"test out" of certain courses, but more likely you'll just repeat them and find them easier if you've already done something similar. Most courses in graduate school aren't quite that interchangeable anyways, besides some foundation courses meant to get everyone on the same page (since neuroscience is so interdisciplinary).
